# How to create macro to copy the entire content of one word document to multiple other word documents with the same existing format

Tags: macros, documentation

I'm having a word document and the content of the word document to be copied into multiple word documents(more than 50) with the same text and formatting.

All the words documents are having different headers, so that I can't simply copy the word document. Only the content in the word document to be copied into other documents by running a macro.

Can you please help me.?

I'm not a developer of Macro coding but I can understand the coding provided from your end.